# Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.</error_description><error>access_denied</error></oauth>*

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing **Spring MVC + Spring Security OAuth2** example.

In this example I was using the

- Spring Security version
  `<springsec.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</springsec.version>`
- Spring MVC version `<spring.version>4.0.9.RELEASE</spring.version>`

But my business client wants to update Spring and Security dependencies to their latest versions. I changed

- Spring MVC to `<spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>` and
- Security to `<springsec.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsec.version>`.

I was able to successfully deploy the application, however when I tried to get an access token using below CURL command I got the following error. Why ?

```
C:\>curl -vvv -X POST "http://localhost:8080/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password&scope=read,write,trust"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/oauth/token?username=user1&password=user1&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&grant_type=password&scope=read,write,trust HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D3BE17423B26618D2931A9B317E422E1; Path=/demo.rest.springsecurity.oauth2.0.authentication/; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 11:19:28 GMT
<
<oauth><error_description>Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.</error_description><error>access_denied</error></oauth>* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

C:\>
```

My **pom.xml** for reference:

```
<properties>
        <!-- General Properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- <springsec.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</springsec.version> -->
        <springsec.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsec.version>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <!-- <spring.version>4.0.9.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- Jersey Server -->
        <jersey-version>1.19</jersey-version>

        <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
        <spring-security-oauth2-version>2.0.10.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2-version>

        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.21</jcl-over-slf4j.version>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP, CGLIB, JSTL -->
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security core, web, config, aspects, taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springsec.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsec.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core, Context, Support, beans, test, Web MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- logging, slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 

        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" method="GET" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never" 
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.LogoutImpl" >
        <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.ClientDetailsServiceImpl"/>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager" 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider  ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
        class="demo.oauth2.authentication.security.CustomUserAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <!-- <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" /> -->

    <bean id="tokenStore"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices" 
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"></property>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />   <!-- Declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers  @RequestMapping, @Controller -->

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="MyResource" class="demo.oauth2.authentication.resources.MyResource"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. In order to vanish the `"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found."` error we need to simply add `<sec:csrf disabled="true" />` to all element to `<http`> tag like below.

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" auto-config="true"  create-session="stateless"  authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" > 

        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" /> 
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" auto-config="true" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" method="GET" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> -->
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never"  auto-config="true"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"   />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <!-- Added this to fix error -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>
```

Comment: But I'm facing other issues too: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot' - maybe not public?